# Why is it better to let your wheels roll in ice?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, ice

I've recently read that if you're driving in icy conditions and begin to slip, it's better to not tap on the breaks, and instead, allow the vehicle's wheels to continue rolling. Why is this the case? It doesn't seem very intuitive. I think it probably has to do with static and kinetic friction, but I can't put it together.

Comment: "best" braking and control is achieved by the max braking possible **without** causing the wheels to lock...

Comment: @SolarMike is correct. The accepted answer is not correct

Comment: @AaronStevens here's an example of stunning winter driving :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RSn7OyBdhM if only I had 1% of the talent...

Comment: @AaronStevens I meant to accept the answer and the comment you posted below. I can vote for your answer if you post one. I'll upvote some of your other answers so you can receive credit though

Comment: @ElonMusk Thank you for the sentiment, but that isn't necessary. Only upvote answers by me if you think those answers are useful in the context of the question they are for. I'm not free enough to type up an answer now, but I might do it later.

Comment: The answer by @JMac should be accepted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're right, it does deal with static and kinetic friction. We know that in this situation (whether we tap the brakes or not), the frictional force is acting opposite to the car's motion. Let's consider both scenarios:

***Applying brakes***: When we apply the brakes, the wheels are "locked up", so they are simply being "dragged", therefore the wheels are experiencing a kinetic frictional force. The net frictional force (acting against the car's direction of motion) can be calculated using F = N×μk, where N is the normal force of of the car (N = m×g), and μk is the coefficient of kinetic friction.

***Not braking***: When we don't apply brakes, the wheels are actually experiencing *static* friction. This is because at any given instant when the car is moving, the  whole wheel is actually **rotating** around a **fixed** point, which is the point of contact between the wheel and the ground. So, at that instantaneous moment, the point of contact is not moving, and therefore doesn't experience kinetic friction, only static friction. Similar to kinetic friction, the formula for static friction is F = N×μs, where the value of μs is greater than the value of μk.

So, the static friction force is greater than kinetic friction force, which means that if the tires are rolling, there will be more frictional force, so greater deceleration, meaning quicker slowdown.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Static friction is *not* equal to $\mu N$. Furthermore, rolling without slipping is not sufficient for static friction to act maximally. You want to pump the brakes. No brakes at all will not help you stop faster.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why they would think that.

Tapping the brakes is almost definitely going to be better than not tapping the brakes. 
 Using the brakes causes the static friction between your tires and the road to increase; which slows down the car more.

The issue is that when the grip between the brakes and the tire is too strong, the coefficient of friction between the tires isn't high enough to maintain that static contact.  This is when the wheels "lock up" and begin to skid.  As you mention, kinetic friction is less than static friction, so wheel lock and skidding should be avoided.

This means that *tapping* the brakes is generally the best braking method in these conditions, as compared to not braking at all.

When considering *modern* vehicles, your friend missed the mark even more.  Most vehicles sold now (as far as I know) have an ABS, an [Anti-lock Braking System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-lock_braking_system) which actually disengages the brakes when they reach the threshold when you start to lose traction.  Basically, you can push down on the brake pedal as hard as you want, and you can feel the brakes start "tapping" on their own, to prevent skidding, increase traction, and allow you to brake in the lowest space possible.  Tapping is the method most cars automatically employ on icy surfaces, and if you try it for yourself (in a controlled environment), you will find that tapping the brakes should slow you down a lot faster than not pressing it at all; especially if you avoid skidding.